# What is the purpose of Kafka ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

What is the real purpose of setting `ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` to a kafka producer. The doc says

> An id string to pass to the server when making requests. The purpose
> of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just
> ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in
> server-side request logging.
>
> Default: (empty)
>
> Property: client.id

So, it seems that the producer sends this information to the broker/topic/partion. But, how can this information be retrieved/verified at server. **Importantly, Can the consumer read/retrieve this (client.id) information and find by which producer a message was published.**

And what happens when two producers knowingly or unknowingly use the same client.id.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the producer client id is only useful in the context of having an authorizer class at the server-side to approve/deny clients to topics rather than just host-based access. Distributed Tracing libraries might also use it to display information about producer requests

The id is not forwarded to consumers

There's nothing the server can do to track duplicate clients, as the cluster wouldn't have knowledge of the use cases for each producer. All it would know is the producer is running on more than one host, and sending binary data to more than one topic.
If you add authorizers like I mentioned, where clients need to request explicit access to topics, then you'd quickly find overlaps in topic access

Comment: thanks `The id is not forwarded to consumers` +1. That helps. But with no mechanism to verify it, any producer can set any client.id.

Answer (score 0):

An id string to pass to the server when making requests. The purpose of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in server-side request logging.

Default: (empty)

Property: client.id